# reduce is throwing push of undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

The first one is working fine but the second one is throwing  colorArray.push is not a function

```
var primaryColors = [
    {color:'red'},
    {color:'yellow'},
    {color:'blue'}
];

   primaryColors.reduce((colorArray,primaryColor)=>{
             colorArray.push(primaryColor.color);
          return colorArray
            },[])
```

The below code is  throwing colorArray.push is not a function

```
  var primaryColors = [
        {color:'red'},
        {color:'yellow'},
        {color:'blue'}
    ];
    primaryColors.reduce((colorArray,primaryColor)=>{
        return colorArray.push(primaryColor.color);
        },[])
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

Comment: `array.push` returns a number, not an array.

Answer (score 2):

[`Array.prototype.push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) returns the new length of the array, which is a number not an array. You need to either use two separate lines, or you could take advantage of the comma operator and the implicit return feature of arrow functions, as well as ES6 destructuring and do this:

```js
var primaryColors = [{
    color: 'red'
  },
  {
    color: 'yellow'
  },
  {
    color: 'blue'
  }
];

const res = primaryColors.reduce((colorArray, { color }) => (colorArray.push(color), colorArray), []);
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning the actual array in the second reduce function but the output of Array.prototype.push. Which returns the length of array.

reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

Comment: As stated in the page that you link to, it returns the new length of the array. Not the index at which the element was pushed.